# Grammaire, une apparente apposition : « trente employés ses collègues » (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: appositions

> Des trente employés ses collègues, pas un, bien entendu, qui n’eût son petit classement, côté cour ou côté jardin ;

Il n'y a pas de virgule après « employés », au cas contraire de quoi on comprendrait assez naturellement que « ses collègues » est une apposition à « trente employés ». Quelle autre explication peut-on donner autre qu'une négligence, soit chez l'auteur soit dans les ateliers de typographie ?

Comment: Hey, I cannot edit your post for a so small number of characters, so here you go : "as" becomes "**p**as" and "G" becomes "**«**"

Comment: @Marck Done, thanks.

Comment: La phrase est peut-être incorrecte grammaticalement (attendons de voir les réponses), mais l’absence de virgule se justifie d’un point de vue littéraire. "Des trente employés ses collègues" est un tout uni vis-à-vis du reste de la phrase ; il serait inenvisageable de respirer après "employés" dans une lecture publique du texte.

Comment: @Graffito Votre commentaire est en fait une réponse, et en plus avec une référence ; faites une réponse ; les réponses dans l'espace commentaire sont  fortement découragées ; les commentaires n'apparaissent pas sur la Toile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette figure de style est effectivement une **apposition** que l'Académie Française définit ainsi :

> Apposition, en termes de Grammaire & de Rhétorique, est une figure qui
> joint un substantif à un autre sans particule conjonctive, & par une
> sorte d’ellipse, pour marquer quelque attribut particulier de la chose
> dont on parle. Ainsi dans ces exemples, Cicéron l’Orateur Romain,
> Attila le fléau de Dieu, Ses pleurs témoins de sa douleur.

La virgule n'est pas nécessaire.

Comment: Assez stylé, en vrai. Ce Courteline a l'air d'avoir un style intéressant après tout. Ca donne envie de le lire :-)

Comment: Pas de lien vers une source quelconque ? //  En fait le célèbre « Maitre Corbeau » est une apposition sans virgule, plus, il est le représentant de toute une classe courante d'appositions (à laquelle je n'avais même pas pensé). https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9A2241

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que cette omission pouvant lier les termes "Des trentes employés" et "ses collègues" est une **[asyndète](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/asynd%C3%A8te)**. On pourrait facilement glisser "qui sont" ou "étant" entre les deux expressions, donnant :

- *Des trentes employés **étant** ses collègues ...*
- *Des trentes employés **qui sont** ses collègues ...*

D'autres constructions :

- ***Pour cette amie sa confidente**, la situation n'était pas surprenante.*
- ***Du salaire son dû**, il ne dépensait que peu.*
- *La victoire eût pu être facile, même pour **une équipe des plus mauvaises**.* [en vérification]

Comment: On peut lire dans LBU que les éléments coordonnés sont _ordinairement_ séparés par une virgule. comment expliquer l'absence de la virgule. Êtes-vous plus ou moins familier avec cet usage de l'asyndète sans virgule ?

Comment: @LPH oui ! J'ai rajouté des exemples dans ma réponse

Comment: D'où les tenez-vous ? Votre inspiration ? Une source à laquelle je viens d'accéder tend à confirmer ce fait ; la virgule est souvent utilisée : https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/linguistique/asyndete-figure-de-style (vous pouvez utiliser cette source si vous voulez, mais il y en possiblement de meilleures, à vous de voir).

Comment: @LPH en quelque sorte, ce sont des formulations que j'utilise régulièrement à l'oral ou à l'écrit, et que j'entends et lis également souvent. La troisième plus particulièrement : on utilise en réalité très souvent cette formulation. Exemples (de la vie courante) : *Un tournoi des plus captivants.*, *Une vie des plus modestes.*, *Un des moins bons restaurants de la ville.*, etc.

Comment: @Marck Tu crois que ton troisième exemple est de même nature que les deux premiers? Je ne suis pas bien sûr (je ne connais pas la réponse correcte, mais instinctivement, j'aurais dit que c'était un peu différent).

Comment: @Frank si je rajoute "qui est" entre "équipe" et "des plus mauvaises", cela fait sens. Cependant, tu me mets un doute car, en effet, cela signifie réellement "qui fait partie des plus mauvaises équipes".

Comment: @Marck - peut-être mon doute à moi vient-il de ce que _un X des plus mauvais_ est très courant, comme tu le notes, alors que _pour cette amie sa confidente_ ne viendrait pas aussi naturellement, à l'oral en particulier.

Comment: Il me semble que « des plus mauvaises » ne peut pas être analysé comme étant coordonné. Le TLFi présente « de » comme une préposition qui introduit le superlatif ([Le compl. du superl. abs. exprimant une intensité forte] Des plus + adj. = Parmi les plus + adj.).